# Why EF is not returning entity with fresh data from DB after FirstOrDefault call (EF6)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, load, find

I have some code (more complex than in this example) where I don't understand why the FirstOrDefault call, which clearly round-trips to DB, is not returning a fresh entity from DB:

```
var dbContext = new MyDBContext();

// this will not round-trip to Db if found in context
var user = this.dbContext.EFUsers.Find(someUID);

// some other work here with 'user'

this.dbContext.ObjectContext.Detach(user);

// stuff in disconnected mode
var newUser = new EFUser() { UID = someUID };
// stuff in disconnected mode  

this.dbContext.EFUsers.Attach(newUser);

// finish working with newUser 
// (eg. deletion of many-to-many relation to avoid loading related entities in memory)

user = this.dbContext.EFUsers.FirstOrDefault(us => us.UID == someUID);

// I would expect at this point that 'user' will be queried with fresh values from DB,
// In reality, I get back only the entity with UID filled in, 'newUser' from above


// some update user goes here which fails because of the above

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I thought `Find` will return me the user from the context, if available, but `FirstOrDefault` always a user with fresh values from database.

Can anyone explain? How would I overcome this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worth reading this **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936**,

> "When results are returned from the database, objects that do not
>   exist in the context are attached to the context. If an object is
>   already in the context, the existing object is returned (the current
>   and original values of the object's properties in the entry are not
>   overwritten with database values)."

the load and reload methods are worth a read too.
Sounds like you want that behaviour.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592911.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload(v=vs.113).aspx